# CTE with update

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a simple query using with CTE but is not behaving the way I want to.

The idea is to filter those records wit precio_90 = null and then update the field precio_90 with the price from mytable2 where codigo=codigo on a specific date.
At present I get all records updated without the actual filter.

```
DECLARE @mytable1 TABLE
(
codigo VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
precio_90 NUMERIC(10, 4) 
);

DECLARE @mytable2 TABLE
(codigo VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
fecha date NOT NULL,
precio NUMERIC(10, 4) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @mytable1(codigo, precio_90)
VALUES ('stock1', 51),
('stock1', 3),
('stock1',5),
('stock1',6),
('stock1',2),
('stock1',7),
('stock1',null)

INSERT INTO @mytable2(codigo, fecha, precio)
VALUES ('stock1', '20140710', 26),
('stock2', '20140711', 66),
('stock1', '20140712', 23),
('stock2', '20140710', 35);

;WITH CTE_1
as
( SELECT  codigo, precio_90           
  FROM  @mytable1 
  where precio_90 is null )

UPDATE t1 
SET t1.precio_90= t2.[precio]
from @mytable1 as t1
INNER JOIN @mytable2 as t2
ON t1.codigo = t2.[codigo] and '2014-07-10'=t2.fecha
```

Comment: Try using the CTE in the update instead of the table.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/22705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first, you don't use the CTE anywhere in your update, which is why your results aren't filtered right. Second, you don't need a CTE for this... you can filter `precio_90 is null` right in the update.

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.precio_90= t2.[precio]
from @mytable1 as t1
INNER JOIN @mytable2 as t2 ON t1.codigo = t2.codigo
where t1.precio_90 is null
    and '2014-07-10'=t2.fecha
```

Answer (score 1):

From your sample `@mytable1` INSERTS, all the records inserted with codigo = 'stock1'. Therefore, on your `UPDATE` statement, you update all the records from @mytable1 to stock1 level from @mytable2.

For example, if your sample table 1 had records with stock2 like this:

```
INSERT INTO @mytable1(codigo, precio_90)
VALUES ('stock1', 51),
('stock1', 3),
('stock1',5),
('stock1',6),
('stock2',2), -- Set to stock2
('stock2',7), -- Set to stock2
('stock1',null)
```

Then your CTE is updating the stock2 records as specified from the 7/10/2014 records:

```
codigo     precio_90
---------- ---------------------------------------
stock1     26.0000
stock1     26.0000
stock1     26.0000
stock1     26.0000
stock2     35.0000
stock2     35.0000
stock1     26.0000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   UPDATE t1 
          SET t1.precio_90 = t2.[precio]
     from @mytable1 as t1
     JOIN @mytable2 as t2
       ON t1.[codigo] = t2.[codigo] 
      and t2.fecha = '2014-07-10' 
      and t1.precio_90 is null 
      and t2.precio_90 is null
```